# Separating Javafx 8 GUI from remaining code

Tags: javafx-8

When reading javafx 8 tutorials, this seems to be the main work flow:

```
public class Test extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(TestFXController.class.getResource("test.fxml"));
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            TestFXController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
            controller.plotSomething();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say that I have an Algorithm which I want to run. After starting the above application I may end up with an interface containing a "run algorithm" button. After pressing the button, an action handler invokes the algorithm.
I then have: start java application -> build interface -> press button to solve Algorithm -> display solution. All that separates the graphical stuff from the algorithm is a button. In fact, the graphical interface 'drives' the application in the sense that it is responsible for launching the algorithm.
What I would prefer however is something like this:

```
public class Test2{
    public void main(String[] args){
        Algorithm alg=new Algorithm();
        alg.solve();
        GUI gui =new GUI(); //Spawns a Javafx 8 Graphical User Interface
        gui.displaySolution(alg.getSolution());
    }
}
```

To me, this seems a lot cleaner? I'm however not sure how to do this with javafx 8, or whether this is even possible? Any examples or references are highly appreciated. What should I put in the GUI class such that it launches a javafx 8 interface?
The example in Test2 would also open up possibilities to use a clean Observer Design Pattern like this:

```
public class Test3{
    public void main(String[] args){
        Algorithm alg=new Algorithm();
        alg.addListener(new GUI()); //Add a Javafx 8 GUI as a listener.
        alg.addListener(new TextualLogger());
        alg.solve();
    }
}
```

Notice that in the classes Test2 and Test3, the GUI no longer drives the application.

To clarify, my main question would be: what should be the implementation of the GUI class if I would run the code in Test2? Something like this:

```
public class GUI extends Application{

  public GUI(){
    //What should I put here? Perhaps launch(new String[]); ?
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(TestFXController.class.getResource("test.fxml"));
    Parent root;
    try {
    root = fxmlLoader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void displaySolution(Solution sol){
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: If the only step between launching the application and having the result be displayed is the "Solve Algorithm" (etc.) button being pressed, you can "programatically" simulate the button being pressed using a method such as [`fire`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#fire%28%29) (haven't actually used the `fire` method, but it should work if it works like Swing's `doClick` did)... still, there are better ways to have your GUI components be populated automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a JavaFX application, you should think of the `start(...)` method essentially as the equivalent of the `main(...)` method in a "regular" Java application. (In fact, in Java 8, a JavaFX application does not need a `main(...)` method at all.) This mechanism for launching a JavaFX application was introduced in order to force the programmer, as much as possible, to initialize the UI on the correct thread (in comparison to Swing, where there is a large amount of code published which launches the GUI incorrectly). For convenience, the `start(...)` method is passed an initial stage, but there is no requirement for you to use it if you prefer to use a different one.

So you can just do

```
public class Test2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Algorithm alg = new Algorithm();
        alg.solve();
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.displaySolution(alg.getSolution());
    }

    // included for the benefit of IDEs that do not support
    // launching an Application without a main method:
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

and now `GUI` is not an `Application` subclass (which makes sense, because it represents the GUI, not an application):

```
public class GUI {

  public GUI(){

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(TestFXController.class.getResource("test.fxml"));
    Parent root;
    try {
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void displaySolution(Solution sol){
    ...
  }

}
```

One thing to bear in mind here is that `start(...)` is executed on the FX Application Thread. Consequently, once you have shown the UI, any further long-running processes that need to be performed should be executed on background threads. In the use-case you've described, all the heavy lifting is done before you show the UI, so this is not an issue, but you may need to consider this if you try to extend this pattern at all.

Comment: This is just perfect! Thanks a lot! I'm really happy with this, especially with your explanation! It works very well and is much cleaner than any of the approaches I've seen so far. It's a bit weird that I couldn't find any other examples like this.

Comment: You're welcome. Be aware of the caveat re threads (see update to answer).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your caveat. a. why would it matter whether I do heavy computations after the GUI has been drawn (i.e. after stage.show() is invoked)? Any references to this problem or a potential solution? Is there a clean way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Because you would be doing them on the FX Application Thread, so the UI would not be able to update while the computations were in progress (i.e. the UI would freeze). The fix would just be to do as you normally do: perform the computations in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I follow exactly what you are attempting to do - are you trying to open a second JavaFX Window?

Would something like this work?

```
Scene resultScene = algorithm.getSolution();
Stage resultStage = new Stage();
resultStage.setScene(resultScene);
resultStage.addEventHandler() or addEventFilter()
resultStage.show();
```

This stage can be it's own window or a child of the primaryStage so that if you close the parent, it will also close.

Comment: I' ve updated the question with a clarification. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Is there a reason you are looking to start a new JavaFX Application Process, rather than just opening a new stage?

Comment: No reason. I just want to plot something graphically using JavaFX. The tutorials I found all start with the code I put in the Test class (first code snippet). All I'm looking for is to run Test2 which makes a new instance of GUI, and GUI opens up some graphical window using Javafx 8.

Comment: By using an approach as noted above - you can launch a second window in JavaFX (you will have your primary stage, and the new stage).    If you get access to the controller of the view you should be able to instantiate something on it to render your new GUI.  If you want only one window, you can simply generate the node and scene and replace what is currently in the primary stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to open second JavaFX window from one already running. You can visit.

[Launch JavaFX application from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873769/launch-javafx-application-from-another-class/37760704#37760704)

It will solve your issue.

below is the code how to run new JavaFx Application

```
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new MainApp().start(new Stage()); // MainApp is the class name of your second Application
            }
        });
```

Make your class extend Application and Implement Runnable and add below mention code in that class

```
@Override
public void run(){
    launch();
}
```

launch() method will be called from run() method. Do not use Main() method in the second class, else it with throw exception.