# How to get a reference of a running JavaFX application for testings with JUnit

Tags: java, javafx, junit

it isn't a new issue for sure, but I couldn't find a nice solution for my problem, so I will try to find one on my own.

I have given an `Application` class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        // ...
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        // ...
        super.stop();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test methods from its controller and so on.. Not the GUI, but other things.

So, for this, I thought, I create an `instance` of this `Application`, start it and then I make something like `instance.getXY(...)`. Is it the right purpose?

A little example for a `JUnit` class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitTests {

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        // this starts the application, but I don't get a reference from it
        javafx.application.Application.launch(TestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I've found this [Launch JavaFX application from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873769/launch-javafx-application-from-another-class) to get an refrence of the `Application` class. But it don't seems to be a nice solution for me.

How would you fix my testing problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need an instance of the Application for testing?

Comment: Because the Application is starting a network connection, is sending different things to another point, gets responses and so on.. So, I want to simulate something like "the app is starting", "the user is sending something" (by invoking the sending method out of JUnit), then I would wait a few seconds and proof if a response came in. If I make this out of a JUnit test class, I need a reference of the Application class, don't I?

Comment: I can't see your code base, but I'd except you to be able to fake such calls in other ways.

Comment: Mh, but for this calls I need for example the network connection session built by the application.

Comment: Why are you doing things like that in the `Application` class though? I would factor those out into a service class of some kind. Then you can just unit test the service class etc. The `Application` subclass should just have minimal code to invoke startup and shutdown functionality on other classes.