# How can I a run method I've created automatically when a stage starts in javafx without hitting a button?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a scene called homepage.fxml in my application. It has a Linechart in it and I created a button to refresh the chart (that's when the data is displayed). What I want is for the data to be displayed in the chart once the stage commences. I'm guessing I need to call the method (refreshPressed()) when the app starts but I'm a novice programmer so please help me out. I also looked at this: [link to something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873769/launch-javafx-application-from-another-class) but it's not helping.

Comment: by calling it as soon as the stage commences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `initialize()` method of the controller for your FXML, invoke [`fire()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#fire--) on the button.

Code snippet from the controller:

```
@FXML Button button;

public void initialize() {
    button.fire();
}

@FXML
public void refreshPressed() {
    // refresh chart.
}
```

Corresponding snippet from FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="button" text="Refresh" onAction="#refreshPressed"/>
```

Comment: Wow...just like that and the magic happened. Thanks! Awesome!

Comment: Good workaround to trigger the button in initialize(). Thank you!