# JavaFX not available, what now?

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX application, but when people try to run it nothing happens because they got no JavaFX on their system, because they are using OpenJDK for example.

What can I do to inform people about the problem?

Best way would be to have an Alert informing the user about that, is there a way to do this with basic Java functionality?

Comment: When you say that got no JavaFX Do you mean doesn't have Java 8+? But still have some versión of Java?

Comment: If the user does not have Java installed, you can't really use Java to display a message. Generally, you should distribute your application with a bundled copy of the JRE included.

Comment: @gonzaloan I mean 'has only openJDK 8' installed, for example

Comment: @Zephyr the assumption is that the user has Java installed, that's why I am asking for basic Java functionality

Comment: you can use pure awt (or swing even) for an initial interaction

Comment: @kleopatra indeed so, but how can I do that?

Comment: don't understand where's the problem? start with awt/swing, check whether or not the fx classes are available, in the first case launch the fx app, in the second inform the users and back out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Swing App to start and check if Java FX is avalaible like this:

```
private static boolean isJavaFxAvalaible() {
        try {

            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("javafx.application.Application");

            return true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If this is true, just load your Main JavaFX, here's an example:

[Launch JavaFX application from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873769/launch-javafx-application-from-another-class)

hope this can help you.